# How to allow users to only edit their Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using asp.net mvc 4  with razor syntax

I want to  How to allow users to only edit their Data  using session

I tried that :

```
   @model ProcRec.Models.Candidat

   @{

   if (Session["ID"] != Model.Id.ToString())
    {

    Session.Abandon();

    Response.Redirect("~/Candidat/LoginCandidat");

      }
```

but  it's not working  (   Session["ID"] != Model.Id.ToString()   always true. )

Comment: The MVC template includes a completely functional login system. Did you choose not to use it for a good reason?

Comment: actualy  the user of my application  Login  just  for editing some data   i'm using database to store password an name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  this  :

```
   @model ProcRec.Models.Candidat

    @{

    if (!Session["ID"].Equals(id.ToString())) 
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            return RedirectToAction("LoginCandidat", "Candidat");
        }
```

because  your  session["ID"]   is typed as object   not  as a string    ( ==  is  used  to  compare strings  that  are typed  as string  .....)